# why onhover css backround image not loading properly on firtst time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

we are using a large image as a background for a div after loading the page if we hover on that div we are getting blank for a few seconds why is that? Can we have a solution for that? I need a solution without using a sprite image because I need to alter that image in responsive

```css
.hexagonal{
  background: url(/images/service-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.hexagonal:hover {
  background: url(/images/service-bg-over.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagonal">
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I wont write the solution for you, but basically, you could do this in JS like so: event listener on hover -> load image in cache -> when image loaded, set background-url of div to that image.

Comment: You can preload the images. There are different methods to do it, [here](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) you can see a few

Answer (score 0):

because this image is large it's taking time to load it and that is why you see blank for a few seconds when you hover the element.

In order to fix it, you'll have to preload those images you need when hovering. there are some ways to do it and there are a few suggestions in the comments for JS solutions but I think using the CSS way is more suitable since you won't need the JS part.

In order to preload images using CSS, you can set the content of the after pseudo-element of the body to those images and then hide the element.

```
body::after{
   position:absolute; 
   width:0; 
   height:0; 
   overflow:hidden; 
   z-index:-1; /* hide images */
   content: url(/images/service-bg-over.jpg);   /* load images */
}
```